# Not releasing Twilio.Device instance on trying to setup new Device for another application

Tags: javascript, twilio

We are developing a conferencing application using javascript client.

**We have a scenario wherein a user is connecting to one of the applications  and after a while needs to connect to another Twilio Application under different sub Account**

Second Time when we have to connect to another Twilio application using

```
    Twilio.Device.setup(token, { rtc: true,debug:true });
```

we get log something like

```
**[Device] Found existing Device; using new token but ignoring options**  
[Device] Unable to receive incoming calls  
[Device] Registered listener for event type "error"  
[Device] Registered listener for event type "connect"  
[Device] Registered listener for event type "disconnect"  
[Device] Registered listener for event type "ready"  
[Device] Registered listener for event type "offline"  
[Device] Invoke listeners for event type "ready"


**[Application-Ready-EvtHandler] Twilio.Device is now ready for connections : ready
[Application-Ready-EvtHandler] Twilio.Device is now ready for connections : ready (Raised Second Time for old Device)**
```

**seems like previous Device is not getting released**

(Number of times ready event is fired == Number of times we have to use Twilio.Device.Setup )

and I'm unable to connect to subsequent Twilio applications after connecting to the first.

Subsequently calling
   **`Twilio.Device.connect({ agent: currentUserName, debug: true });`**
throws an exception i,e, "Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error."

How to switch to subsequent Twilio Applications using twilio.js Library?

EDIT: 
P.S. Notice that this is an issue in IE and firefox only , which do not support web-rtc standard. In chrome The event handler are invoked as mentioned but it works!

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jash, I'm Megan from Twilio.

Everything you see in your logs is the expected behavior.

If you want to switch between devices you will need to explicitly call `.destroy()` [as mentioned in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#destroy). This will terminate active and pending connections, triggering the offline event handler. Device will not be able to make or receive new connections until you call `Twilio.Device.setup()` again.

Comment: Thanks Megan, Its been a while when I was working with Twilio. In anticipation I'm marking your answer as correct one. Thanks.